# Inexplicable length of tuple in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Hey fellow programmers,

while coding in a private project (Python 3), I just came across this weird finding which I can't explain.
I have the following (simplified) dictionary

```
dict={
"Test1":((1,"test1"),(2,"test1.2"),(3,"test1.3")), 
"Test2":((0,"test4")), 
"Test3":((5,"test5"),(6,"test6"))
}
```

and am using this to check the length of its entries (the tuples)

```
for item in dict:
    print("len of item is",len(item))
```

Why the heck does Python say each tuple has a length of 5 when it actually varies between one and three?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `for item in dict` iterates over dictionary keys. In your case the keys are `"Test1"`, `"Test2"`, `"Test3"` which are all 5 chars long. Assuming that you want to iterate over values, just use `for item in dict.values()` instead.

Comment: `for k, v in dict.items():
    print("len of item is", len(v))`

Comment: May I ask an additional question to this?

When iterating through a dict like the simplified one above, Python seems to handle tuples with multiple tuples inside differently than tuples with just one tuple inside:
`for subitem in dict[item]: print("subitem is",subitem)`
So when there is just one tuple inside the outer tuple, the second loop dosen't iterate through the outer tuple but through the inner elements of the only tuple that is inside.
How do you guys cope with that in the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item here iterates over the keys, which is why it returns 5 (length of the "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" strings) of the dictionary, what you want is:

```
for val in dict.values():
    print("len of item is",len(val))
```

You could also check each key and value of the dictionary by doing:

```
for key,val in dict.items():
    print("len of key is", len(key))
    print("len of value is", len(val))
```

Comment: Oh man, now I see it. Didn't recognize the need to adress the value of each key..
Thanks for the clarification, been a blockhead just as I expected :D
Went for the tuples as the error source all the time.